# turtlebot gmapping

Tags: navigation, rviz, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so i was following the SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot. The problem is there is no map received error in rviz.
anyone know how to overcome this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192152/turtlebot-gmapping/) by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-08**:
Please add more info about what error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ohh silly me..i run the gmapping on workstation.should run on turtlebot..;)

---

Originally posted by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) with karma: 36 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0